# CSS width transition not fast enough and causes jittery UI when joined with translateX

Tags: javascript, css, touch, css-animations, hammer.js

#### The Code

[Code at CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/demonstration-of-offcanvas-animation-performance-issue-r6qiq) -- [Demo](https://r6qiq.csb.app/)

There is a lot of code in that above codesandbox, so I'll try to paste the relevant parts here:

Based on the series of drag / pan gesture's total X-direction delta, I'm doing:

```
// before setting transform and width, I set the transition
// this way, there will be some tweening that occurs when I do
// change the properties -- relevant to the specific open / 
// close situation
if (this.isOpening) {
  this.content.style.transition = `width 0.1s linear, transform 0.1s linear`;
} else {
  this.content.style.transition = `width 0.0s linear, transform 0.1s linear`;
}


this.content.style.setProperty("--dx", `${nextX}`);
this.content.style.transform = `translateX(${nextX}px)`;
this.resize();


// and then in that resize function
let nextX = parseInt(this.content.style.getPropertyValue("--dx"), 10);
this.content.style.setProperty("width", `${window.innerWidth - nextX}px`);
```

#### The Behavior I Want

When I drag the content to the right and left (either with the mouse, or a touch event), I expect that the right edge of the content will stick to the right edge of the window.  I know that doing translateX by itself has super smooth animation, but animating width is tricky, as it causes reflows, harming performance.

#### The Behavior I'm seeing

When I drag the content to the right and left, the right edge of the content does *not* stick to the right edge of the window. This is partially do to the fact that I'm using dynamic css-transitions depending on the scenario. I have one transition in use for opening, and one for closing (revealing / hiding the sidebar). The reason for this is that if I don't have transitions at all, the animation feels jerky, and very unsmooth.  The way it is now is *better*, but still not not ideal.

#### What I've tried

**No CSS Transitions**

- Right side of the content sticks to the right side of the window, as I want
- but the animation of the left side of the content following my finger is jittery (no tweening between emitted touch events, I think)

**Add transition to the transform property**

- Left side of the content is buttery smooth
- when revealing the sidebar, the right side of the content is pushed outside the viewport
- when hiding the sidebar (dragging to the left), the right side of the content is pulled into the viewport, revealing the background element(s) / body

**Add transition to the transform and width properties**

- had to be situational depending on opening / closing
- the current way I'm doing things (as seen in the codesandbox, and in my actual code in my app)
- translateX animation is less smooth
- width animation still goes off screen a little bit, but it doesn't reveal the body / background

#### Other Notes

I'm currently using hammerjs to get touch events / gestures -- I don't have to use this library, so if there is a better way to achieve what I want, I'm all ears.

I guess the last thing I haven't tried is `requestAnimationFrame`? not sure if that would help here based on what I've read -- but at this point I'm willing to try anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out after continuing to search for solutions, and eventually stumbling on this page: [MDN's *"Using the Web Animations API"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API).

The gist of it is that while css animations use the `@keyframes` declaration in a css file, the Web Animations API enables us to call `.animate` on an element, and allows many of the same options as the css way of animating.

I'm very glad I discovered this API, as it has play, cause, and cancel abilities, which I don't be using for this sidebar animation, but it might mean that when evaluating an animation library, such as [ember-animated](https://ember-animation.github.io/ember-animated/), I could check to see if it uses the animations API to achieve cancellation, resulting in reduced payload size.

#### What worked

[Code on CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/demonstration-of-offcanvas-animation-performance-issue-b9tuw) -- [Demo](https://b9tuw.csb.app/)

The key differences are:

- I got rid of any attempt to set the `transition` property. (went back to the first thing under ***What I've Tried***)
- the snap open and snap closed behavior was too quick, so, using the Web Animations API, I was able to smoothly animate both translateX and width -- even on my non-high end older phone, a Sony XPeria XZ1 (Compact)

  ```
   // e is a hammer.js Pan event 
   handleDrag(e) {
    // setup and various math omitted

    if (e.isFinal) {
      // code determining if a "snap" open or shut should happen
      // and what that x-axis value should be 
      // are omitted

      // reset state omitted 

      // call the Web Animations API 
      return this.finish(nextX);
    }

    // fallback code for when the gesture is still active
    // directly updates the transform property
    // (though, I should probably look in to using requestAnimationFrame
    // to improve performance on lower-end devices)
    this.content.style.transform = `translateX(${nextX}px)`;
    this.resize();
  }

  finish(nextX: number) {
    let prevX = this.currentLeft;

    let keyFrames = [
      { transform: `translateX(${prevX}px)` },
      { transform: `translateX(${nextX}px)` },
    ];


    // this covers the main scenario from the question here
    // adding a width animation to the translate X
    // (for medium sized screens and larger, it's important to have both)
    // NOTE: isPushing is a boolean that checks for a certain 
    //       screen size -- if the screen is small enough,
    //       no width animating occurs
    if (!this.isPushing) {
      keyFrames[0].width = `${window.innerWidth - prevX}px`;
      keyFrames[1].width = `${window.innerWidth - nextX}px`;
    }

    let easing = 'cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000)';
    let animation = this.content.animate(keyFrames as any /* :( */, { duration: 200, easing });

    // without the onfinish, the content element will reappear
    // back in its pre-animation position / state.
    animation.onfinish = () => {
      this.content.style.transform = `translateX(${nextX}px)`;

      if (!this.isPushing) {
        this.content.style.setProperty('width', `${window.innerWidth - nextX}px`);
      }
    };
  }
  ```